# Eigen error associated with triangularView of template

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following function that is throwing an error. I can isolate the problem to the line

```
  A.template triangularView<Lower>().solveInPlace(MatrixXd::Identity(p,p)); // the problem line
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how what the problem is an how to fix it.

```
template <typename T, typename RNG>
inline void rInvWishRevCholesky_thread_inplace(Eigen::MatrixBase<T>& A, 
                                                  const int v,
                                                  const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& Psi,
                                                  RNG& rng){
  int p = Psi.rows();
  MatrixXd PsiInv = Psi.llt().solve(MatrixXd::Identity(p,p));
  if (v <= p-1)
    Rcpp::stop("v must be > Psi.rows - 1");
  VectorXd z(p*(p-1)/2);
  fillUnitNormal_thread(z, rng);
  MatrixXd X = MatrixXd::Zero(p, p);
  for (int i=0; i<p; i++){
    boost::random::chi_squared_distribution<> rchisq(v-i);
    X(i,i) = sqrt(rchisq(rng));
  }
  int pos = 0;
  for (int i=1; i<p; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
      X(i,j) = z(pos);
      pos++;
    }
  }
  A.template noalias() = PsiInv.llt().matrixL()*X;
  A.template triangularView<Lower>().solveInPlace(MatrixXd::Identity(p,p)); // the problem line
  A.template transposeInPlace();
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:496:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/SolveTriangular.h: In instantiation of 'void Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<_MatrixType, _Mode, Eigen::Dense>::solveInPlace(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with int Side = 1; OtherDerived = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; unsigned int _Mode = 1]':
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:511:37:   required from 'void Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<_MatrixType, _Mode, Eigen::Dense>::solveInPlace(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; unsigned int _Mode = 1]'
../inst/include/MatDist_thread.h:153:3:   required from 'void rInvWishRevCholesky_thread_inplace(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&, int, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&, RNG&) [with T = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; RNG = boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32, 624, 397, 31, 2567483615, 11, 4294967295, 7, 2636928640, 15, 4022730752, 18, 1812433253>]'
MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:162:72:   required from here
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/SolveTriangular.h:182:11: error: use of deleted function 'Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >& Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::operator=(const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&)'
     other = otherCopy;
     ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:463:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseNullaryOp.h:60:7: note: 'Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >& Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::operator=(const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class CwiseNullaryOp : public internal::dense_xpr_base< CwiseNullaryOp<NullaryOp, PlainObjectType> >::type, internal::no_assignment_operator
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseNullaryOp.h:60:7: error: 'Eigen::internal::no_assignment_operator& Eigen::internal::no_assignment_operator::operator=(const Eigen::internal::no_assignment_operator&)' is private within this context
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:367:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:92:29: note: declared private here
     no_assignment_operator& operator=(const no_assignment_operator&);
                             ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:463:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseNullaryOp.h:60:7: error: passing 'const Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 class CwiseNullaryOp : public internal::dense_xpr_base< CwiseNullaryOp<NullaryOp, PlainObjectType> >::type, internal::no_assignment_operator
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:367:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:115:28: note:   in call to 'Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>& Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>::operator=(const Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>&)'
 template<typename T> class variable_if_dynamic<T, Dynamic>
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:463:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseNullaryOp.h:60:7: error: passing 'const Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 class CwiseNullaryOp : public internal::dense_xpr_base< CwiseNullaryOp<NullaryOp, PlainObjectType> >::type, internal::no_assignment_operator
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:367:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/XprHelper.h:115:28: note:   in call to 'Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>& Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>::operator=(const Eigen::internal::variable_if_dynamic<long int, -1>&)'
 template<typename T> class variable_if_dynamic<T, Dynamic>
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:463:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/CwiseNullaryOp.h:60:7: error: passing 'const Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 class CwiseNullaryOp : public internal::dense_xpr_base< CwiseNullaryOp<NullaryOp, PlainObjectType> >::type, internal::no_assignment_operator
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:425:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/functors/NullaryFunctors.h:31:34: note:   in call to 'Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>& Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>::operator=(const Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>&)'
 template<typename Scalar> struct scalar_identity_op {
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:496:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/SolveTriangular.h: In instantiation of 'static void Eigen::internal::triangular_solver_selector<Lhs, Rhs, Side, Mode, 0, -1>::run(const Lhs&, Rhs&) [with Lhs = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; Rhs = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; int Side = 1; int Mode = 1]':
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/SolveTriangular.h:179:21:   required from 'void Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<_MatrixType, _Mode, Eigen::Dense>::solveInPlace(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with int Side = 1; OtherDerived = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; unsigned int _Mode = 1]'
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/TriangularMatrix.h:511:37:   required from 'void Eigen::TriangularViewImpl<_MatrixType, _Mode, Eigen::Dense>::solveInPlace(const Eigen::MatrixBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; unsigned int _Mode = 1]'
../inst/include/MatDist_thread.h:153:3:   required from 'void rInvWishRevCholesky_thread_inplace(Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>&, int, const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&, RNG&) [with T = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; RNG = boost::random::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32, 624, 397, 31, 2567483615, 11, 4294967295, 7, 2636928640, 15, 4022730752, 18, 1812433253>]'
MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:162:72:   required from here
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/SolveTriangular.h:102:81: error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::coeffRef(int, int)'
       ::run(size, othersize, &actualLhs.coeffRef(0,0), actualLhs.outerStride(), &rhs.coeffRef(0,0), rhs.outerStride(), blocking);
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:434:0,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigenForward.h:30,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/RcppEigen.h:25,
                 from ../inst/include/MatrixAlgebra.h:4,
                 from ../inst/include/mongrel.h:17,
                 from MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.cpp:1:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:273:10: note: candidate: void Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 0>::coeffRef() [with Derived = Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_identity_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >]
     void coeffRef();
          ^~~~~~~~
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:273:10: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
make: *** [MongrelCollapsed_Uncollapse.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mongrel’
* removing ‘/private/var/folders/x1/9_lpy_fs0kvg0p88td6_df200000gq/T/Rtmp7seVyi/devtools_install_1385330e7ebb0/mongrel’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`solveInPlace` requires its argument to be writable, `MatrixXd::Identity(p,p)` is a read-only expression. (Where would you expect to get the result from that function?)

Maybe what you want is this?

```
A.noalias() = (PsiInv.llt().matrixL()*X).transpose()
              .template triangularView<Upper>().solve(MatrixXd::Identity(p,p));
```